# spring security integrate with facebook connect

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, facebook, spring-security

may i know is there any tutorials/guideliness on spring security integrate with facebook connect

Answer (score 7):

The guys at Springsource have launched 'Spring Social' which is worth keeping an eye on when dealing any social API (including facebook). See http://www.springsource.org/spring-social

Answer (score 2):

Spring Social is great but works only with Spring Framework 3.0+. So watch your spring version because i tried two days to figure out how to make Spring Social work with Spring Framework 2.5 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look at [OAuth for Spring Security](http://spring-security-oauth.codehaus.org/)  and [Authentication - Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to Spring security you need [Spring social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social), see [Signing in with Service Provider Accounts](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/signin.html). A promising blog entry is [Integrating your Java Spring MVC webapp with Facebook – Part 1: Doing the OAuth Dance](http://faheemsohail.com/2012/03/integrating-java-spring-mvc-and-facebook-part-1/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use facbook graph api to request the users info and than parse it like this:

```
        JSONObject resp = new JSONObject(content);
        String facebookid = resp.getString("id");
        String firstName = resp.getString("first_name");
        String lastName = resp.getString("last_name");
        String email = resp.getString("email");
        String phone = resp.getString("mobile_phone");

        JSONObject address = resp.getJSONObject("address");
        String street = address.getString("street");
        String city = address.getString("city");
        String zip = address.getString("zip");
        String state = address.getString("state");
        String country = address.getString("country");
```

After you have the strings calling your registration method should be easy. Than you just have to auto authenticate them.

I have posted more details about this here:
[Facebook Connect example in JSP (tomcat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184959/facebook-connect-example-in-jsp-tomcat/5265028#5265028)