# Spring Security integration with Facebook Connect

Tags: security, spring, authentication, facebook, spring-security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [spring security integrate with facebook connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942984/spring-security-integrate-with-facebook-connect)

Spring Security for us uses an email as the username and a password.  To log someone in through code I call:

```
securityContext.setAuthentication(objectWithUsername);
```

How do I then allow facebook connect users to login who don't have an email or password with us?  I can't call the above method because it requires a username.